# How do I use a common axis for three similar time/value graphs

Tags: r, plot, axis, time-series, measurement

I have three timestamped measurement series, taken over the same interval, but with different actual timestamps. I'd like to show these three trajectories in a combined plot, but because the x-axis (timestamps) is different in each case, I'm having some trouble. Is there a way to do this without picking an x-axis to use and interpolating the y-values for the other two measurement series? I'm fairly new to R, but I feel like there's something obvious I'm overlooking.

For example:

#### Series 1

```
Time    Value
1.023   5.786
2.564   10.675
3.678   14.678
5.023   17.456
```

#### Series 2

```
0.787   1.765
1.567   3.456
3.011   5.879
4.598   7.768
```

#### Series 3

```
1.208   3.780
2.478   6.890
3.823   9.091
5.125   12.769
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data (real or fictional) so that we will know what type of time/date data you have?

Comment: That's better, you can make our lives easier if you instead use `dput(data)`, where data is wherever you got series1, series2, and series3

Comment: Rguy, could you expand on that? How can my question be improved by dput?

Comment: @william - dput will let others copy and paste the exact structure of your data into our R sessions. This is often the easiest and most efficient way to communicate data. It ensures that the type of data is consistent with your R session, and eliminates almost all possibilities of differences between your R session and others.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. So for long datasets, you'd just show the first couple rows?

Comment: @William - exactly. Something like `dput(head(dat))` often does the trick. Or sample from your data to capture a random effect that is important, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With base graphics, you can use a combination of `plot` and `points` or `lines`:

```
dat1 <- data.frame(Time = c(1.023, 2.564, 3.678, 5.023), Value = c(5.786, 10.675, 14.678, 17.456))
dat2 <- data.frame(Time = c(0.787, 1.567, 3.011, 4.598), Value = c(1.765, 3.456, 5.879, 7.768))
dat3 <- data.frame(Time = c(1.208, 2.478, 3.823, 5.125), Value = c(3.780, 6.890, 9.091, 12.769))

with(dat1, plot(Time, Value, xlim = c(0,6), ylim = c(0,20)))
with(dat2, points(Time, Value, col = "red"))
with(dat3, points(Time, Value, col = "green"))
```

Take a look at `?legend` to add a legend. Or, learn `ggplot2` and let it handle that part of it for you:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)
plotdata <- melt(list(dat1 = dat1, dat2 = dat2, dat3 = dat3), "Time")

qplot(Time, value, data = plotdata, colour = L1)
```

Comment: you are missing library(reshape) from which the function melt comes.

Comment: Thanks @patrickT, fixed. This answer was from the days when reshape was loaded when calling ggplot2...that no longer happens.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
t1 <- "Time Value
1.023   5.786
2.564   10.675
3.678   14.678
5.023   17.456"

t2 <- "Time Value
0.787   1.765
1.567   3.456
3.011   5.879
4.598   7.768"

t3 <- "Time Value
1.208   3.780
2.478   6.890
3.823   9.091
5.125   12.769"

tex1 <- read.table(textConnection(t1), header = TRUE)
tex2 <- read.table(textConnection(t2), header = TRUE)
tex3 <- read.table(textConnection(t3), header = TRUE)

plot(tex1, type="l", xlim=range(tex1$Time, tex2$Time, tex3$Time), ylim=range(tex1$Value, tex2$Value, tex3$Value), main="Common Time Axis for 3 Data Series", col="black")
grid()
lines(tex2, col="red")
lines(tex3, col="blue")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Without any further information, it seems you're going to have to use a combination of: `points` and `xlim`.
Plot a single combination of the points (or lines) using `plot`, passing the `xlim` argument so that all of your time inputs could fit on the plot.
Then, use `points` or `lines` to add the other data to the plot, and maybe pass a `color` parameter to these functions as well to distinguish the outputs.
We can provide more details if you include a minimal reproducible example!

Comment: That'll work & is much better than interpolation. At least I know now there's no obvious easier way I've overlooked.

Comment: @Chase provided a more thorough answer above, and his works well!

Answer (score 0):

Subtract the minimum value for time in each series. Determine maximum of the three results as your xlim[2]. Plot  using matplot with label suppression, and then add your labels= and at= with axis().